# Have an issue with Integer.parseInt(string)

Tags: java, string, integer, parseint

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String str = input.nextLine();  // reads x , y
        int x = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(",")));   // this reads the numbers until comma
                                                                                                                                    
        System.out.println(x);
```

when i do this i don't get an error

```java
22, 23
```

but when i do this

```java
22 ,23
```

i get the following error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "22 "
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at scratchFiles.stringArray.main(stringArray.java:9)
```

Comment: Because you split at `,` and `22 ` is not a parseable number because of the trailing space whereas `22` is parseable

Comment: thanks for your response, i figured that much, my question should have been what should i do in order to make the splitting end at the end of the entered number

Comment: Looks like there even is a newline in there as the error message has a line break in it.

Comment: You can use `trim()` to get rid of leading and trailing spaces

Comment: thanks, i learned a new function today @QBrute

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` to return a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace removed so that it can be parsed to an `Int`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String str = input.nextLine();  // reads x , y
    int x = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(",")).trim());
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you try to get the first number the string returned from substring from "22 , 23" is "22[whitespace]".
With Integer.parseInt() you can only pass an integer string as a parameter otherwise it will through an error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String str = input.nextLine();  // reads x , y
    // get string till , and remove any trailing whitespaces
    String numString = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(",")).trim();
    int x = Integer.parseInt(numString);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

There are few things you should be careful about if string is something like this "22 3, 34" you will still get an exception. So be careful about sanitizing your string first and then pass it to Integer.parseInt()

Comment: well what do you mean by sanitizing, as in like return a warning if the thing is not written right?

Comment: @BDR by sanitizing I mean you should make sure the string should only contain digit which you are going to pass in Integer.parseInt() function